# maximum cost value in a 2D array having sum less or equal than a given number

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D-array and a number `K`.

PROBLEM: we have a matrix `cost[][]` and each cell of the matrix represents a cost to traverse through that cell. we start at the top left `(0,0)` and we have to reach the last cell (bottom right). I have to write a function that returns the cost of maximum cost path to reach `(m,n)` without exceeding the number `K`.

The total cost of a path to reach `(m, n)` is the sum of all the costs on that path (including both source and destination) and the sum should be less or equal than `K`. We can only move down, right or diagonally down-right.

If we can't find a path having a maximum sum less or equal than `K` we return `-1` and the value of the matrix cannot be negative

Solution: I tried a lot of codes but none of them returned the results I expected.

**My first solution was to transform the 2D array in a simple array and to apply the knapsack algorithm** but it didn't work because logically the path were not followed. (*the logic of the exercise disappeared with this idea*)

I tried also a recursive formula but it didn't work. I got an error "*max recursion depth*".
When I solved this recursion problem my algorithm didn't take into account the constraint of the number not to be exceeded.

I don't need the code, I just want some explanations to be able to solve the problem (especially the mathematical formula).
thanks

Example:

```
    if we had this 3*3 matrix:
    cost[][] = {{2,3,1}, {6,1,9},{8,2,3}}
    and k = 7
```

the answer should be `6 :(0,0)->(1,1)->(3,3)`

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the size of the input array, or time efficiency?

Comment: No there have no constraints on the size and for the time we have to do a naïve algorithm (recursive) first and after we have to use dynamic programmic to avoid the repetitive work on the recursion tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we think about it as searching for the smallest remaining non-negative magnitude as we subtract the cost on our way from the end to the start, a naive recurrence could be something like the following. A memoised recursion is sometimes better suited than an iteration on the full dimension of `k` because many inputs can yield idiosyncratic sets of sums.

```js
function g(m, K, i, j, k, memo){
  if (k < 0 || i < 0 || j < 0)
    return K + 1;

  if (i == 0 && j == 0)
    return k >= m[i][j] ? k - m[i][j] : K + 1;
    
  const key = String([i, j, k]);
  
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
    return memo[key];
    
  return memo[key] = Math.min(
    g(m, K, i-1, j, k - m[i][j], memo),
    g(m, K, i, j-1, k - m[i][j], memo),
    g(m, K, i-1, j-1, k - m[i][j], memo)
  )
}

function f(m, k){
  return k - g(m, k, m.length-1, m[0].length-1, k, {});
}

var m = [
  [2,3,1],
  [6,1,9],
  [8,2,3]
];

var k = 7;

console.log(f(m, k));
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it's very helpful. It was not necessary to give me the algorithm just an explanation should have been enough. But it's nice to you

Comment: anonymous ah, ok. I thought that since the recurrence is so compact, it would be easy to show in code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `dp[i][j]` is the cost to go to the location `(i,j)`, then the cost depends on the cost to reach its previous location from where the current location be reached :

- diagonally down-right `(i-1,j-1)`
- or down a column `(i-1,j)`
- or right `(i, j-1)`.

Now the equations can be written as:

```
dp[i][j] = -1
if ( cost[i][j] < K ):
    dp[i][j] = if ( dp[i-1][j-1] != -1 and cost[i][j] + dp[i-1][j-1] <= K ) :
                  dp[i][j] = cost[i][j] + dp[i-1][j-1]

               if ( dp[i-1][j] != -1 and cost[i][j] + dp[i-1][j] <= K ) :
                  dp[i][j] = max( dp[i][j], cost[i][j] + dp[i-1][j] )

               if ( dp[i][j-1] != -1 and cost[i][j-1] + dp[i][j-1] <= K):
                  dp[i][j] = max( dp[i][j], cost[i][j] + dp[i][j-1] )
```

Using these you can build a bottom up `dp` array and your answer will be `dp[m][n]` where `m x n` is the size of the 2-d array.